# Getting the closest point in a direction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Lets say I have a 2D coordinate system with lots of Rects on it. Take this as an example representation. I now want to get the nearest next element in a given direction. Lets use this image as an example:

[image]

**S** defines the element at which I currently am. If I press up I should now be at the closest element in upwards direction which is **A**. My current approach was something like this:

```
Distance = abs((S.x-A.x)+(S.y-A.y);
Angle = abs(atan2((A.y - S.y), (A.x - S.x)) * 180 / Math.PI);
Score = Distance + abs(DirectionAngle-Angle)
```

Then I choose the candidate based on the lowest score. Now there are multiple problems:

- Iteration happens for ALL elements, not only those upwards. The elements are not considered if they're in the opposite direction but the elements to the left and right are still in the calculation.
- If **A** for some reason extends 3 more pieces to the left it won't work anymore and **B** is selected.

So what I need is a solution to only iterate over elements in the direction AND a smart solution to only select the closest element and then stop and return the element.

Btw. the elements are actually divs so canvas is not an option.

Comment: How constrained are your directions (e.g. multiples of 90 degrees only?)  What is your data structure?  What's _supposed_ to happen if A is moved three spaces left?

Comment: Yes, multiples of 90 degress only, basically arrow keys. Currently I only store the mid points of all objects and iterate over them selecting the best candidate based on the things I posted. Structure of a point is [Number(x), Number(y)]. Those are held in a simple array. Edit: If A would be 3 pieces to the left then B should be the next piece. If A is extended 3 pieces to the left it should still be the next piece.

Comment: If you want to catch the case of A being extended you should also store the rects' width and treat the case where the left and right edges are to either side of your current location as optimum (0°, say). (And you'll need the height for the east-west directions, of course.)

Comment: Right now I'm thinking it would be a better idea to check for the closest vertex in that direction. That would raise the amount of checks for each keypress by 4 though or if optimized to at least by 2.

Comment: @SargoDarya you don't need to check every vertex, just check against `min(abs(A.x0 - S.x), abs(A.x1 - S.x))` for example (that being the delta-x of the nearest x coordinate)

Answer (score 2):

Might this giant overkill example help?

You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/Cu88x/

where i first determine the position of the clicked element, get all elements matching a certain direction (check if the point is inside the rectangle)

```
    var offset = helper.offset(element),
    rect = new helper.simpleRect(offset.left - (3 * 20), offset.top - (3 * 20), 6 * 20, 6 * 20),
    left = getElements(DIRECTION.LEFT, element, rect),
    right = getElements(DIRECTION.RIGHT, element, rect),
    up = getElements(DIRECTION.UP, element, rect),
    down = getElements(DIRECTION.DOWN, element, rect);
```

and then calculate the distance between the elements that already match the direction (in case 2 are the same distance away, they also get highlighted as the closest):

```
function highlightClosest(arr, direction, rect) {
    var i = 0, l = arr.length, min = 10000, el, minScoreElement = [], o, a, b, c;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        el = arr[i];
        o = helper.offset(el);

        a = Math.abs(o.left - rect.center.left);
        b = Math.abs(o.top - rect.center.top);
        c = (a * a) + (b * b);

        if (c < min) {
            min = c;
            minScoreElement = [el];
        } else if (c == min) {
            minScoreElement.push(el);
        }
    }
    if (minScoreElement) {
        for (i = 0; i < minScoreElement.length; i++) {
            minScoreElement[i].className = direction;
        }
    }
}
```